# how to use array_pop in PHP MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
$host    = "localhost";
$server  = "root";
$pass    = "";
$db_name = "table_name";


try {
    $dbc = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $server, $pass);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}


$query = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM table_name ");


while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $q = array_pop($query);
}
```

I get this error message `Warning: array_pop() expects parameter 1 to be array`.

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not passing the `$row` you're passing the `$query` (which is not an array). pass the `$row`

```php
$q = array_pop($row);
```